# Uncaught URIError: URI malformed with reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, iso-8859-1, recaptcha

On some pages that have an encoded part in the url, like `%FC` instead of `ü`, I get a `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed` error in the console and the captcha therefore is not working.

Our Project is `iso-8859-1` encoded and there is nothing I can change about that.

Do you know a workaround that could fix this? I'm using reCAPTCHA 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution now is, that before the `recaptcha/api.js` is executed, I grab the `window.location.pathname`, get rid of the problematic elements and exchange it in the url with `history.pushState`. If I'd simply changed the `window.location.pathname` a page redirect would be the consequence.

Here is my example code:

```
var oldPath = window.location.pathname;
var newPath = decodeURIComponent( unescape( unescape(oldPath)));
var stateObj = {};
history.pushState(stateObj, "", newPath);
```